# I need help with getting npcs to move in in terraria

Tags: terraria

Hello my npcs are not moving in although i have a house with all the requirements and 68 silver coins i have also 30 gold coins i say this because i 
want a merchant

Comment: Other than being a duplicate, we would need screenshots to see whether anything is wrong.

Comment: Or we could just tell him the usual... Like, make sure you walls are covering all of the background, even a little bit good muck it up. You need a source of light, a seating item (beds count), a table (can be crafting), and a door. It also has to be at least 7x8 and needs to be away from corruption.